# Can "all of which" be used as the subject of a sentence?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-fragments

For example, I wrote this:

However, offering anything more specific than first, second, and third class will slow processing times, increase customer inconvenience and customer inequality, all of which will dampen the customer service experience JetBlue values so highly.

...but can I split it into two sentences like this?

However, offering anything more specific than first, second, and third class will slow processing times, increase customer inconvenience and customer inequality. All of which will dampen the customer service experience JetBlue values so highly.

Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, you can; it's fine. It is a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause. "Which" is anaphoric to the entire preceding clause. It has a finite verb phrase "will dampen the customer service experience JetBlue values so highly" ("will" is a tensed verb).

Answer (score 2):

No, this does not work. "All of which will dampen the customer service experience JetBlue values so highly" is a relative clause, and as such, it is dependent. Only an independent clause can be used in a sentence on its own.

Comment: But sentence fragments are not unacceptable per se (though they are probably better avoided in more formal registers).

Comment: Ok, so "all of which" means the same thing as "which" which is a relative pronoun which is why this is a relative clause and, therefore, dependent? However, according to this website:http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/relative-clauses/       relative pronouns can also lead to independent clauses. For example, they say that "The person" is a relative pronoun.

Comment: @Jiga No, you're misreading that article (though it _is_ poorly expressed). Note that the article has already stated: '... a “relative pronoun,” which **substitutes** [bolding mine] for a noun, a noun phrase, or a pronoun when sentences are combined'.  They mean << 'who' is the relative pronoun substituting for the subject 'the person' of the second sentence in the uncombined version. >> I'm sure you agree that 'the dog' (also in red) can't possibly be a relative pronoun.

Comment: Supplementary (non-defining)  relative clauses can constitute a separate sentence, provided they contain a finite VP, compare A: "Our rent is due next week". B: "Which is why we shouldn't be going out to dinner tonight".

Comment: Disagree.   Strip 'Of which' and you are left with all.  This is not an incomplete sentence.

Comment: Jason P Sallinger, the existence of a subject ("all" in this case) does not imply completeness of a sentence. A non-elliptical clause, such as the one in question, must have a subject and a predicate (or just a predicate in the imperative mood).